# How to get REST API body info(JSON)?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use the OpenWeather Rest API, but I'm having issues accessing the body info. I am using Postman to test, which works, but not in my code, so I am missing something.

Postman results: *(I'm not displaying the entire body content as it's not that necessary)*
REST endpoint with queries: api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London, uk&APPID=*api-key-here*

```
{
"coord": {
    "lon": -0.13,
    "lat": 51.51
},
"weather": [
    {
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain"
    }
],
"main": {
    "temp": 290.38
},
"name": "London"
}
```

The endpoint works fine on Postman.

My code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
```

**Inside my LocalWeather function:**

Variables:

```
const [weather, setWeather] = useState([]);
```

useEffect to run my fetch call

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, []); //  Run once on load
```

Actual fetch call:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&APPID=${api-key`);
    res.json()
    .then(res => setWeather(res))
}
```

I could then log out headers (Which gives me relevant info):

```
console.log(res);
```

I've had to add the following before because the useEffect acts like the componentDidMount and runs after initial render.

```
if (!weather.length) {
    return null;
}
```

Then I would try to render the info if I'm following the Postman results:

```
return (
    <ul>
        <li>{weather.weather[0].main}</li>
    </ul>
);
```

What obvious thing am I missing that's preventing me from displaying the body info?

Getting the following on the console, which tells me that it's not actually getting any information.
*Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0*

Comment: can you add a log of` `console.log(res)`?

Comment: Returns all of the Postman results

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that `fetch` thinks the URL is relative. Since you do not have the URL prefixed with `https://`, `fetch` is making the request relative to whatever page you are currently on. For example: `http://localhost:3000/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather`.

Whatever that page is (probably a 404 page), it likely isn't JSON so it fails to parse it when you do `res.json()` which is why you get the JSON syntax error.

If you add the `https://` prefix, it should work!

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&APPID=${apiKey}`);
  res
    .json()
    .then(res => setWeather(res))
}
```

Comment: That helps, but I am still getting an empty array with a length of 0.  `Array(0)length: 0__proto__: Array(0)`.  Also using the res.weather that weiklr mentioned.

Comment: @Mitchell Are you getting the full API response as a result of `res.json()`? What output do you get if you switch `.then(res => setWeather(res))` with `.then(res => console.log(res))`?

Comment: I get all of the Postman results by switching it to a console.log

Comment: Then I can get the main level items by doing 
`<ul>
            <li>{openWeather.name}</li>
            <li>{openWeather.cod}</li>
            <li>{openWeather.id}</li>
            <li>{openWeather.timezone}</li>
            <li>{openWeather.dt}</li>
            <li>{openWeather.visibility}</li>
            <li>{openWeather.base}</li>
</ul>`
But I cannot get into the nested items. weather[0].main doesn't work. Is there a stringify or something I'm missing to access nested items?

Comment: @Mitchell Hmm, you shouldn't need to do any parsing. I'm not super familiar with how React Hooks work so maybe there is an issue in that which I don't see... Is the array empty if you do this? 
`const fetchData = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&APPID=${apiKey}`);
  res
    .json()
    .then(res => {
   setWeather(res)
   console.log(res.weather)
 })
}`

Comment: coming back undefined doing it that way. I've tried using axios as well, but same thing.

Comment: Very odd. Is there a `weather` property when you log `res`?

Comment: Getting something new: `Promise {<pending>} __proto__: Promise  [[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"  [[PromiseValue]]: undefined`

Comment: `.then(res => console.log(res));` is returning undefined

Comment: That is even more strange. If you run this just in your browser's console, does it work? https://gist.github.com/nprail/c5bd1d458a9664010f233c006397d686

Comment: It does work, although, I am getting a `Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: undefined `    And then it displays all of the results.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Noah's answer, if you only need the weather array, you could just setWeather(res.weather) in useEffects instead like this:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&APPID=${apiKey}`);
  res
    .json()
    .then(res => setWeather(res.weather))
}
```

By doing so, you can avoid the if check you did here:

```
if (!weather.length) {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: That helps. But in this case, I want access to the whole response. If I do this `.then(res => setWeather(res.weather[0]));` then I can render with `{weather.main}`, but then I can only get main which right now renders rain. I also want to display name.

Answer (score 0):

So somebody on a Slack channel figured this out for me.

When returning JSX:

```
<li>{openWeather.weather && openWeather.weather[0].main}</li>
```

This feels like a bug to me, but it does output the response from the REST API.

I am still getting a warning, which I am unsure why:

```
    const axiosGet = () => {
        const data = axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&APPID=api-key`)
        .then(data => setWeather(data.data));
    }
```

It's saying `Line 14:15: 'data' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars`, although everything works. Aren't I setting the rest endpoint to data, and then using it when running the setWeather method?

Comment: That warning is more of a code style issue. The `data` variable in `const data = axios.get...` is a different variable than the one in `.then`. So even though you are using a variable named `data` in `.then`, it is not the same variable. Essentially, you could just drop `const data =` from the beginning.